# Can the mods email a possibly disgruntled user?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52371/what-was-the-state-of-the-german-rail-system-in-1944/) from a new user got well received after OP clarified her intents. Unfortunately, she seems to have taken offense that we initially wondered if she was a neo-nazi troll, and never came back...

Is there any way mods can email her to gently nudge her back? Suggested email if so:

> We noticed you haven't showed up on the History Stack Exchange since you've posted your question. FYI it ended up very well received by the community after an edit clarified what you were up to, and three great answers await you on the site.
>
> [What was the state of the German rail system in 1944?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52371/what-was-the-state-of-the-german-rail-system-in-1944/)

More generally speaking, could SE do this automatically (does it already?) for upvoted questions with answers whose authors are no shows?

Edit: upon further investigation, it *seems* she has two accounts if the deleted answer to the question is anything to go by, and that she actually has come back:

https://history.stackexchange.com/users/37647/olivia

https://history.stackexchange.com/users/37649/olivia

The two should probably be merged if that is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, can mods email a user? Well, yes. Sending a mod message will also send an email. However, this wouldn't be an appropriate use of the feature. That feature is to be used for moderation purposes only - such as suspensions suspensions or warnings. A poke to a user who may have quit isn't what this is for.

However, SE does send emails automatically to people if they have unread inbox notifications, depending on their settings. So if you want to send a message, leave a comment. They'll either see it on site or in the email from SE.

If a user has two accounts, they should go to /contact and request a merge of the accounts.

Comment: Only thing I'd add to this is that the best way to bring back a disgruntled user is almost certianly to not get them disgruntled in the first place. (And of course a lot of folks are wandering the Internet barely gruntled to start with)

Comment: Isn't a crucial part missing? The OP here had status "(unregistered)"? Making email contact impossible? Therefore: "Can mods (or like you explained 'the system') email a *registered* user?"

Comment: @LangLangC *pretty* sure even unregistered users have to put it an email at some point when posting. There's no guarantee that it's a valid email, though.

Comment: Yep. The box says "required" but it's not checked for validity (at all?) nor a guarantee for match to real user (& could be disposable)? // Plus: this is then volatile, some users *can't* 'come back', as their credentials are now lost to them?

Comment: @LangLangC - right. If you don't provide valid credentials, then you essentially forfeit access to the account once your cookie is gone.